# RPGLE Compile Error: "The Name Or Indicator Is Not Defined"

Tags: rpgle

I am taking an introductory course to IBM iSeries and Rational Developer, and I'm having difficulty compiling one of my RPGLE programs for a lab... Unfortunately, the lab is just a walkthrough of code we are supposed to compile without much explanation, so I have absolutely no clue about what I'm doing....

When I compile my program MARKSRPG.RPGLE, most of my errors say "The Name Or Indicator Is Not Defined"... I don't know what this means, and I'm unable to move ahead to see if what I have coded works thus far.

***(UPDATE: I've made corrections to the suggestions, and now I'm getting different errors. "The types of the left and right hand side do not match in the EVAL operation", and "Operands are not compatible with the type of operator.)***

The program is broken up into two files: MARKSRPG.RPGLE and MARKSDSP.DSPF. Here is the code for both, but my errors only show up on MARKSRPG.RPGLE

MARKSDSP:

```
 A          R RECORD1
 A                                  1 33'Marks Calculator'
 A                                  2  2USER
 A                                  1  2SYSNAME
 A                                  1 72DATE
 A                                  4 24'Test 1:'
 A                                  5 24'Test 2:'
 A                                  6 24'Test 3:'
 A                                  7 24'Labs:'
 A                                  8 24'Exam:'
 A            TEST1          3  0B  4 32RANGE(0 100)
 A            TEST2          3  0B  5 32RANGE(0 100)
 A            TEST3          3  0B  6 32RANGE(0 100)
 A            LABS           3  0B  7 32RANGE(0 30)
 A            EXAM           3  0B  8 32RANGE(0 100)
 A            FIELD           T  B  2 71

 A          R RECORD2                   CA03(03 'Exit')
 A                                      OVERLAY
 A                                 10 23'Tests:'
 A                                 11 18'Final Mark:'
 A                                 12 17'Final Grade:'
 A            TESTOVRLL      3  0O 10 30
 A            NUMGRADE       3  0O 11 30
 A            GRADE          2X  O 12 30
 A                                 13 17'F3 - Exit'
```

MARKSRPG:

```
  FMARKSDSP  CF   E             WORKSTN
 DLETGRADE         S              1A
 DTESTOVRLL        S              3A
  /FREE
       EXFMT RECORD1;
       DOW NOT(*IN03);
               EXSR GETGRADE;
               WRITE RECORD1;
               EXFMT RECORD2;
               IF *IN03= *OFF;
                 EXSR CLEARMARKS;
                 EXFMT RECORD1;
               ENDIF;
             ENDDO;
       *INLR = *ON;
       RETURN;
       BEGSR GETGRADE;
         LETGRADE = 'F';
         TESTOVRLL = (TEST1 + TEST2 + TEST3)/3;
         NUMGRADE = (TESTOVRLL/100*.30) + LABS +(EXAM/100*.35);
        ENDSR;
        BEGSR CLEARMARKS;
          TEST1 = 0;
          TEST2 = 0;
          TEST3 = 0;
          LABS = 0;
          EXAM = 0;
          TESTOVRLL = 0;
        ENDSR;
  /END-FREE
```

If you know of any useful resources for learning RPGLE and CLLE I'd appreciated it, and
any additional insight and help would be great too!

Thanks.

Comment: In your DSPF member you say `TESTOVRLL` is a 3,0 field (3 digits, 0 decimals) but in your RPGLE member you define `TESTOVRLL` as a 3A (3 alpha characters) field. Just remove the D spec for `TESTOVRLL` in your RPGLE member and then recompile. Edit your question with your updated code and any error messages.

Comment: @Benny Hill - When I removed the D spec for `TESTOVRLL`, I get the errors `Expression contains an operand that is not defined`, and `The name or indicator TESTOVRLL is not defined`

Comment: Put the D spec back in for `TESTOVRLL` but instead of defining it as a `3A`, define it as `3 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your RPGLE member you have the wrong name for your display file. You have `MARKSRPG` instead of `MARKSDSP`.

I don't see LETGRADE defined anywhere either, that should go in your D specs.

```
D LETGRADE           s            1a
```

I also don't see the subroutine `CLEARMARKS` defined anywhere. Since I also don't see an /end-free anywhere I'm going to assume you didn't paste all of the code for your RPGLE member.

Make those two changes I mentioned and then come back with any questions.

Here's a link to IBM's information center for the IBM i: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzasd/sc09250802.htm

Comment: Could you specify where I insert the line: `D LETGRADE           s            1a`.... As i said I am unfamiliar with the syntax so I'm lost.

Comment: D-specs should follow your F-specs

Comment: I made the corrections to my code, but I'm still getting errors. first error is `TESTOVRLL = (TEST1 + TEST2 + TEST3)/3;             RNF7416: The types of the right and left hand side do not match in the EVAL operation.` The second is `NUMGRADE = (TESTOVRLL/100*.30) + LABS +(EXAM/100*.35); Operands are not compatible with the type of operator.`

Comment: @mdzura117 - check your spelling: sometimes you use `TESTOVRLL` and sometimes you use `TESTOVRALL`.

Comment: @Benny Hill Yes I corrected all the spelling that I can see but I'm still getting errors... Is there a way to paste all my code again? it won't fit in the comment box

Comment: @mdzura117 - sure. There is an "edit" link underneath your question, just click on that. It would be best if you posted your complete code for the RPGLE and DSPF members.